# Expected value of the stochastic integral $\int_0^t e^{as} dW_s$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

I am trying to calculate a stochastic integral 
$\mathbb{E}[\int_0^t e^{as} dW_s]$. I tried breaking it up into a Riemann sum 
$\mathbb{E}[\sum e^{as_{t_i}}(W_{t_i}-W_{t_{i-1}})]$, but I get expected value of $0$, since $\mathbb{E}(W_{t_i}-W_{t_{i-1}}) =0$. But I think it's wrong.  Thanks!

And I want to calculate $\mathbb{E}[W_t \int_0^t e^{as} dW_s]$ as well, I write $W_t=\int_0^t dW_s$ and get  $\mathbb{E}[W_t \int_0^t e^{as} dW_s]=\mathbb{E}[\int_0^t e^{as} dW_s]$.

Is that ok?

($W_t$ is brownian motion.)

Comment: @Srivatsan: $W_s$ is very common notation for standard Brownian motion or *Wiener process* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process)

Comment: And the expected value is zero, for the reason mentioned in the question (although to be rigorous you should be careful taking the limit).

Comment: I think our [stochastic integral] tread is quite poor, so maybe we can re-tag appropriate question with this tag.

Answer (score 8):

The expectation of the Ito integral $\mathbb{E}( \int_0^t \mathrm{e}^{a s} \mathrm{d} W_s )$ is zero as George already said.

To compute $\mathbb{E}( W_t \int_0^t \mathrm{e}^{a s} \mathrm{d} W_s )$, write $W_t = \int_0^t \mathrm{d} W_s$. Then use Ito isometry:

$$
 \mathbb{E}( W_t \int_0^t \mathrm{e}^{a s} \mathrm{d} W_s ) = \mathbb{E}\left( \int_0^t \mathrm{d} W_s \cdot \int_0^t \mathrm{e}^{a s} \mathrm{d} W_s \right) = \int_0^t (1 \cdot \mathrm{e}^{a s}) \mathrm{d} s = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{a t} - 1}{a} \phantom{hhhh}
$$

Comment: Nice answer. Btw, I think our [stochastic integral] tread is quite poor, so maybe we can re-tag appropriate question with this tag.

Comment: Is it possible to give more detailed explanation about how we calculate expected value as '0'?

Comment: @Ilya for the second part, your third equation/integral should be with respect to s, not t. Meaning:
$$ E\Bigg\[\int_{0}^{t}dW_s \int_{0}^{t}e^{as}dWs\Bigg] = \int_{0}^{t} (1\cdot e^{as})ds $$

since by the Itô integral 'multiplication table': $$dW_s \cdot dW_s = ds$$